# Binding to a converter in UWP

Tags: data-binding, uwp, windows-runtime

I wonder if it is possible in UWP to bind to a converter like this:

```
{Binding Path=Value, Converter={Binding ElementName=control, Path=Converter, Mode=OneWay}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I need this for a UserControl, on which the consumer can set the `Converter` property according to his needs. The binding expression above doesn't work for me, but I'm not sure if it is because I've done something wrong or if it is because the framework doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binding.Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding) is regular property not a *DependencyProperty* thus binding won't work here. Like [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#every-binding-involves-these-pieces):

> A binding target. This is a *DependencyProperty* of the *FrameworkElement* in your UI that displays the data.

More information about *Data Binding* you will find [at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/).

Comment: Ok thanks! As a workaround I now bind to a property on the UserControl that wraps around the "Value" property on DataContext and calls the converter. It's a bit cumbersome but works!